# How to retrieve data from Google Sheets in Python without hard coding the ranges?

Tags: python, gspread

```
async def players_d1(ctx):
    try:
        sheet_index = 0  # first sheet
        sheet = workbook.get_worksheet(sheet_index)
        values = sheet.range('A14:A25')

        # Creating an embed
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Players in DIVISION I", color=discord.Color.red())

        # fields for each cell
        for i, cell in enumerate(values, start=1):
            embed.add_field(name=f"Player {i}", value=cell.value, inline=False)

        # sending the embed
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        await ctx.send("An error occurred while fetching data from the worksheet.")
```

I am trying to change the sheet.range to where whenever there's empty cell after a cell with data, it will retrieve that data. Currently, I've set it to A14:A25 where the relevant data for embedding exists. However, the Google Sheet I work with varies daily, and I'm looking for a more effective approach to handle this dynamic process.

This is my first Stack Overflow question so if anyone needs anymore information please feel free to ask, would love help on this.

Comment: can't you use some `for`-loop (or `while`-loop) to check if cell is empty and later modify range? You have string `'A14:A25'` so you can modify it as any other string, or you can generate it with string functions - ie, `col ="A' ; start = 14 ; end = 25 ; text = f"{col}{start}:{col}{end}" ; values = sheet.range(text)`

Comment: Does the data always start at the 14th row? Or does the start row also vary? If the data always starts at the 14th row then `len(worksheet.col_values(1))` to determine how many rows are in column A and then calculate off that. `values = sheet.range(f'A14:A{len(worksheet.col_values(1))-14}')`

Comment: Thanks! didn't know about the `col_values()` worksheet method